# Test In app purchase in waiting for review status for ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

Currently My app's Version 2.0 is live.

Recently I have uploaded version 2.1. I have made sandbox mode disabled from app which I am using for renewal subscriptions.

Now My app V2.1 is in waiting for review status. During this period when I am testing the app, it shows me [Environment:Sandbox] while testing In-App purchases.

I am trying to make in app purchase by downloading the app from test flight i.e. V2.1

V2.1 is in waiting for review mode and I am trying to restore my in app purchases with V2.1 which I already bought with V2.0.

Will this sandbox environment be disabled automatically by apple once the app is live?

Or there is anything I am missing?

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by "I have made sandbox mode disabled from app which I am using for renewal subscriptions."?

You won't get sandbox once you use app downloaded from AppStore. It's related to how the app is signed - test flight build is ad-hoc distributed which implies you get sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable sandbox in your app. Your provisioning profile will control which servers the IAP process looks at. You need to generate an app that's signed for Release to access the Prod IAP server.